# My code should play audio clip after the Dice Roll "Stop" is displayed and Button disabled. But audio plays before and "Stop" displayed afterwards

Tags: python, button, audio, lambda, call

**strong text**   The following code works fine except for one thing. The audio should play after the win result.. i.e after the "Roll the Dice " button display changes to "Stop" and the button is disabled. However the reverse happens.. So what's Wrong? What should be changed? Is there a way to call two functions sequentially using Lambda function? will appreciate some help

## program for a simple set of 2 Dices play. No 6 from  Both Dice wins. Disables the Dice Roll

```
#button and Dice Roll Buttondisplays "Stop". No of attempts also displayed as well.
# Since two Dices are involved other than  "Roll the Dice " button all labels are used twice
# to show the result of these two Dices
           
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import *
from playsound2 import playsound
import time
            
         
# flashing text part of the code
flash_delay = 500
            
# msec between colour change
flash_colours = ('Yellow', 'red') # Two colours to swap between
            
def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(foreground = flash_colours[colour_index])
    window.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)
                
            
# roll function called by btn_roll
a=7
def roll(a):
    lbl_result["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))
    lbl_resultA["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))
                
    if  lbl_result["text"] == "6" and lbl_resultA["text"] == "6":
        lbl_result1["text"] = " U Win"
        lbl_resultB["text"] = " U Win"     
                           
        flashColour(lbl_result1, 0)
        flashColour(lbl_resultB, 0)
        btn_roll["text"] = "Stop"
        btn_roll['state'] = DISABLED
        play(a)       
    else:
        lbl_result1["text"] = "Try Again"        
        flashColour(lbl_result1, 0)
        lbl_resultB["text"] = "Try Again"
        flashColour(lbl_resultB, 0)                  
            
# Clicked functions to count no  of clicks activated till button displays "Stop".       
count = 0
            
def clicked(): 
    if lbl_result["text"] <= ("6")and lbl_result["text"] <= ("6"):
        global count            
        count = count + 1            
        lbl_result3.configure(text=f'No of clicks = {count} ')
                    
                    
count1 = 0      
def clicked1(): 
    if lbl_resultA["text"] <= ("6") and lbl_result["text"] <= ("6"):
        global count1            
        count1 = count1 + 1            
        lbl_resultC.configure(text=f'No of clicks = {count1} ')
        return count1           
           
# play function to play a sound clip once the button displays stop. I want this to happen after the button diplay turns stop and is disabled. But this always happens before that..**

# if no of clicks before reaching 6-6 on both Dices is less than 35 this function plays "good job" audio clip.
#otherwise " finally" clip 
r=7        
def play(r):                
    if  count1 <=35 :
        playsound ('C:/Users/mural/C Language/goodjob.mp3')
    else: playsound ('C:/Users/mural/C Language/finally.mp3')        
    
 # Main tKinter Block                   
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("DICE GAME")         
            
            
window.columnconfigure(3, weight=1, minsize=150)
window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1, minsize=50)
frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame1 = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame2= tk.Frame(master=window)
frame3= tk.Frame(master=window)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5, pady=5)
            
btn_roll = tk.Button(master =frame,bg ="YELLOW",fg = "BLUE",text="Roll the Dice ",font= ('ARIAL 15 underline'),width = 12,height =1,relief = tk.RAISED,command=lambda :[roll(a),clicked(),clicked1()],state =  NORMAL)              
lbl_result = tk.Label(master = frame2,width = 2,height =1,text = "HI",bg="GREEN",fg="YELLOW",font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",15))
lbl_resultA = tk.Label(master = frame1,width = 2,height =1,text = "HI",bg="GREEN",fg="YELLOW",font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",15))
lbl_result1 = tk.Label(master =frame2,text = "Start",font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",8),width = 6,height =2,bg="BLUE",fg="YELLOW")        
lbl_resultB = tk.Label(master =frame1,text = "Start",font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",8),width = 6,height =2,bg="BLUE",fg="YELLOW")                
lbl_result3 = tk.Label(master =frame2,text = "No of Attempts",relief = tk.GROOVE,font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",8),width =12,height =1,bg="BLUE",fg="YELLOW")                
lbl_resultC = tk.Label(master =frame1,text = "No of Attempts",relief = tk.GROOVE,font = (" ARIAL ITALICS",8),width =12,height =1,bg="BLUE",fg="YELLOW")        
            
btn_roll.pack(padx=5,pady=5)       
lbl_result.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
lbl_result1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
lbl_result3.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
lbl_resultA.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
lbl_resultB.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
lbl_resultC.pack(padx=5, pady=5)       
            
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using after method ( which is built-in in python3) I could resolve this issue

```
# roll function called by btn_roll
a=7
def roll(a):
lbl_result["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))
lbl_resultA["text"] = str(random.randint(1, 6))
            
if  lbl_result["text"] == "6" and lbl_resultA["text"] == "6":
    lbl_result1["text"] = " U Win"
    lbl_resultB["text"] = " U Win"     
                       
    flashColour(lbl_result1, 0)
    flashColour(lbl_resultB, 0)
    btn_roll["text"] = "Stop"
    btn_roll['state'] = DISABLED
    window.after(500,play(a)) # using after the sound plays only after display changes
```